# How to write a sub query within another subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

How do I go about writing a query for: for each coral that has at least 2 samples during 1/1/2007 and 1/1/2008, list the coral name and the number of samples.

I think it needs a sub query but I have tried putting things around other ways and it's just  no working for me. Would some be able to just 'spell it out' for me so that I can understand what is actually going on and attempting similar queries to this.

**TABLES**

REEF [reefname, latitude, longitude, 2006_bleachedarea, summer_maximum_monthly_mean_temperature]
Key: reefname

REEFTEMP [reefname, dateofreading, temperaturereading]
Key: reefname, dateofreading

CORAL [coralcode, coralname, thermalthreshold]
Key: coralcode

CORALSAMPLING [sampleno, coralcode, reefname, dateofsampling, bleachpercent]
Key: sampleno

This is what I have so far. I doubt it is correct at all.

```
SELECT coralcode, sampleno
FROM coralbleach__coralsampling 
WHERE 
dateofsampling BETWEEN '2007/1/1' AND '2008/1/1'
GROUP BY sampleno
```

Comment: Not quite understand what exactly you are looking at. Please add the tables and some data in http://sqlfiddle.com and expected result to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do a simple join, something like;

```
SELECT coral.name, COUNT(coralsampling.sampleno) number_of_samples
FROM coral 
JOIN coralsampling 
  ON coral.coralcode = coralsampling.coralcode
 AND coralsampling.dateofsampling BETWEEN '2007/1/1' AND '2008/1/1'
GROUP BY coral.name
HAVING COUNT(coralsampling.sampleno) > 1
```

This query will get all corals, join them with their respective samples and group by the coral name (that means we can use `COUNT` to count the number of sample rows per coral name)
We then use `HAVING` to filter out all corals that don't have 2 samples or more.

Joins are a bit too complex to describe in detail in a short answer format, but I strongly suggest you read up on JOIN and GROUP BY to be able to construct queries like these easily.